# Will uninstalling SQL server ever delete user databases?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have at least one database file that is too big to backup on my server.

I want to make sure when I uninstall a botched upgrade to SQL Server 2008 that it won't delete any of my .mdf files that I've created myself under SQL Server 2005.

I'm pretty sure this is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. it's correct.

Comment: any reference for this?

Answer (score 0):

To be on safer side detach database and back it up.